# Generic type in interface error in Implementation method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have created an interface

```
public interface serviceApi <T extends BaseData>{
 public void  process(T t);
}

class BaseData{...}
class ChildData1 extends BaseData{...}
```

Now when I am implementing a service, I'm getting error

```
class serviceImplOne implements ServiceApi{
   @Override
   public void  process(ChildData1  childData1 ){...} 
}
```

ChildData1 is something which is extending, BaseData.. But seems what I did was wrong.. How to achieve this

Comment: What is the error you are getting? That would help resolve your issue

Comment: From the initial post of what you provided - it doesn't look right. You have an interface (serviceApi) extending the BaseData class. BaseData should be an interface and serviceAPI extending another inteface?

Comment: You need to provide the type argument for `ServiceApi`: `class ServiceImplOne extends `ServiceApi<ChildData1>`.

Comment: @MCEmperor , How can I miss that, I'm sorry,,, but thanks worked.. I've voted your comment